# PTIJ: Hagalah on a suit from a non-Jew

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

Do you have to do Hagalah on a suit that you buy from a non-Jew and if so does dry cleaning count?

Please cite sources if possible.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Bonus points if you can work the legend about Rashi writing שלמה שלמה שלמה שלמה שלמה into this...

Answer (score 1):

From Torah.org:

> Utensils made from any type of metal(1), stone(2), wood(3), bone(4), leather(5), or natural rubber(6) may be koshered by hagalah.

A suit made of leather and rubber would be a most appropriate vessel for this kind of kashering. You could also apply it to belts, shoes, rainboots, saddlebags, but for some odd reason, not tefillin. Perhaps someone else can explain the distinction why.